# integrate google cloud search in gmail add-ons through google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, gmail-addons

I want to make an add-on for Gmail where I can use Google Cloud Search same as we use the calendar add-on. I tried to search on google for it but nothing found useful. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good place to start would be the [Google Cloud Search API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/training/fts_intro/lesson1#summary_and_review).